# React: Data from API not displaying on page after first click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning React and working on a simple "search for recipe" app using an API. I have created a search form component that captures the value in a useState hook then passing the "text" value to the app using "onAdd" prop. The text value should update the url after being passed into a second useState [query]. When I type a term into the form then click the search button, nothing happens. When I click the search button again, the data shows up on the page.

I understand this has something to do with the useState hook being asynchronous and the value not being available until the next render. How can I change this code so the url updates and the data is displayed on the page with a single click?

My SearchForm component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Card from "./Card";
import Button from "./shared/Button";


function SearchForm({ onAdd }) {

    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    const [btnDisabled, setBtnDisabled] = useState(true);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

    const handleTextChange = (e) => {
        if (text === '') {
            setBtnDisabled(true)
            setMessage(null)
        } else if (text !== '' && text.trim().length <= 2) {
            setBtnDisabled(true)
            setMessage('Text must be at least 4 characters')
        } else {
            setMessage(null)
            setBtnDisabled(false)
        }

        setText(e.target.value)
    }

    function submitRecipe(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        onAdd(text)
        setText('');
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submitRecipe}>
            <Card>
                <h2>Find Your Perfect Dish</h2>
                <div className='input-group'>
                    <input onChange={handleTextChange} type='text' placeholder="Search for a Recipe" value={text} />
                    <Button type='submit' version='secondary' isDisabled={btnDisabled} >Search</Button>
                </div>
                {message && <div className="message">{message}</div>}
            </Card>

        </form>
    )
}

export default SearchForm
```

My App component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Header from "./components/Header";
import SearchForm from "./components/SearchForm";
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid'
import Axios from 'axios'
import Recipe from './components/Recipe';

function App() {

  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);

  const APP_ID = 
  const APP_KEY = 
  const url = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`


  const getData = async (text) => {
    setQuery(text)
    const result = await Axios.get(url);
    setRecipes(result.data.hits);
  }


  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="container">
        <SearchForm onAdd={getData} />
        {recipes !== [] && recipes.map( recipe =>
          <Recipe key={uuidv4} recipe={recipe}/>
          )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please don't include secret/confidential information. `APP_ID` and `APP_KEY` should be considered as credentials. Now that they are shared publicly, you should have them discarded and renewed.

Comment: Thank you for catching that, Lars. I removed the keys.

Comment: No problem. Note that they are still available in the activity log of this question, so I would still reccommend renewing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are updating the state, and then performing the call immediately, but the state is not updated before on the next render.

Try this in stead:

```js
  const getData = async (text) => {
    const url = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${text}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`
    const result = await Axios.get(url);
    setRecipes(result.data.hits);
  }
```